# Как передать аргумент в обработчик для кнопок inline-клавиатуры? pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, selenium, telebot

Есть одна проблема, с которой я столкнулся при написании не одного уже бота - как передать аргумент в обработчик для кнопок встроенной клавиатуры типа `InlineKeyboardMarkup`?
Предположим я создал для пользователя экземпляр браузера с помощью библиотеки `selenium` вот таким образом:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://link")
```

Примите во внимание, что переменная `driver` не глобальная и передается с одной функции в другую. Пример кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def Mode1(message):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://link")
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Beta-режим активирован")
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пример 1", callback_data = "Пример 1")
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пример 2", callback_data = "Пример 2")
    key.add(btn1, btn2)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, element.text, reply_markup = key)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="source"]').click()
    return bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, Mode2, driver)


def Mode2(message, driver):
    driver.get("https://link")
    # И так далее
```

И есть обработчик нажатий inline-клавиатуры:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def inline(c):
# def inline(c, driver): # предположительно, что я хочу реализовать
    if c.data == "Пример 1":
        # вот сюда нужно передать экземпляр браузера driver(не глобальной переменной!)
        # чтобы можно было получить объект из этого экземпляра
        #
        #Что-то типа такого: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="source"]').click()
    elif c.data == "Пример 2":
        pass
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где нужно указать в обработчике нажатий аргумент `driver`, который я хочу передать? Не обязательно, чтобы аргумент был `driver` - какой-угодно можно передать, но вопрос в том - каким образом его туда передать?
Каким из способов не пробовал - не получается этого сделать.

Comment: А почему вы не сделаете driver глобальной переменной?

Comment: Вы хотите предоставить пользователю управление вашим браузером?

Comment: Если нет управляйте браузером отдельно а пользователю отправляйте результат ссылку ну или что то ещё

Comment: @Александр, пусть это будет не переменная `driver`, чтобы Вы смогли понять мой вопрос. Пусть это будет обычная локальная переменная, которую я передаю функциям как аргумент и обратно при `return` возвращаю с этим же аргументом. Для примера возьмем, что в какой-то функции я задаю локальную переменную, пусть будет `driver = 'это строка'`. Как мне посредством функции и аргументов передать её в обработчик?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1127169/234134

Comment: @D.Violet, да, спасибо Вам большое за ответ в том вопросе))
Я долго гуглил этот вопрос, и только здесь на стеке смог получить корректный пример.
 Я отметил Ваш ответ как правильный и посчитал его полезным;)