# Как мне передать локальную переменную в обработчик для inline-клавиатуры callback_query_handler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу уже не один бот, и сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой - мне нужно передать переменную в обработчик нажатий inline-клавиатуры. Переменная локальная (примите это во внимание!) и должна передаться в обработчик посредством передачи аргумента, либо же каким-то другим способом (за исключением создания глобальной переменной!!!)

Есть у кого предположения; выслушаю любые идеи. Спасибо)

Код с комментариями:

```
...
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def create(message):
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пример кнопки 1", callback_data = "Пример кнопки 1")
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пример кнопки 2", callback_data = "Пример кнопки 2")
    key.add(btn1,btn2)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Текст", reply_markup = key)
    argument = 'Какой-то текст для примера' # вот эту переменную нужно передать в обработчик
```

```
...
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
# вот сюда нужно передать локальную переменную из другой функции, например argument 
# что-то похожее на это:
# def inline(c, argument):
def inline(c):
    if c.data == "Пример кнопки 1":
        #print('Вот здесь должно появится значение аргумента = ' + argument)
        pass
    elif c.data == "Пример кнопки 2":
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def create(message, f=None):
    if f == 'inline':
        argument = 'Какой-то текст для примера'  # вот эту переменную нужно передать в обработчик
        return argument
    else:
        key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пример кнопки 1", callback_data="Пример кнопки 1")
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Пример кнопки 2", callback_data="Пример кнопки 2")
        key.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Текст", reply_markup=key)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def inline(c):
    if c.data == "Пример кнопки 1":
        print('Вот здесь должно появится значение аргумента = ' + create(None, 'inline'))
    elif c.data == "Пример кнопки 2":
        pass
```