# Как обработать непредвиденный срыв цепочки register_next_step_handler в pytelegramAPI(telebot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

В боте есть цепочка событий, которая поэтапно собирает данные о заказе, который хочет совершить юзер.
Кратко о том, как работает:

1. Бот отправляет сообщение-приветствие по команде /start, тут же появляется inline клавиатура с callback_data.
2. При нажатии бот переходит в нужный Handler (назовем его "заказ").
3. В "заказе" так же inline клавиатура c callback_data. По нажатию независимо от колбэка бот попадает в handler (колбэк нужен чтобы просто типизировать заказы)

Собственно тут и может возникнуть проблема т.к. начинается цепочка запросов юрезу, реализованная через register_next_step_handler. Всего next_step_handler шагов 4.
На любом шаге пользователь может выполнить команду, которая прервет цепочку. При этом в консоли появляется уведомление о попадании в бесконечную рекурсию и бот в лучшем случае раз через раз начинает реагировать на команды, а в худшем - просто падает и нужно перезапускать

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 242, in <lambda>
    e.set = lambda: or_set(e)<br />
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 229, in or_set
    self._set()<br />
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 242, in <lambda>
    e.set = lambda: or_set(e)<br />
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 229, in or_set
    self._set() <br />**RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded**
```

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['LASER','PRINT_3D','OTHER'])
def laser(call):
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Заполните поля заказа")
    chat_id = call.message.chat.id
    order = Order(call.data)
    order_dict[chat_id] = order
    msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Опишите вид работ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler_by_chat_id(call.message.chat.id, get_description)


def get_description(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        order = order_dict[chat_id]
        description = message.text
        order.description = description
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id,  '''Напишите Ваш номер телефона для связи с нами
Используйте только цифры!''')

        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_contacts)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ops')
    
def get_contacts(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        order = order_dict[chat_id]
        contact = message.text
        contact = str(contact)
        if not contact.isdigit():
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Я вижу, что вы ввели не только цифры. Повторите ввод номера')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_contacts)
        else:
            order.contacts = contact
            order.print()
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Пришлите нам файл')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_file)
    except Exception as s:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'ooops')

def get_file(message):
    try:
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        order = order_dict[chat_id]
        _file = message.text
        order.file = _file
        if order.o_type == 'LASER':
            bot.send_message(chat_id,'Все данные введены корректно?' + '\nТип работ: Работа на лазерном станке' + '\nОписание: ' + str(order.description) + '\nКонтактный номер: ' + str(order.contacts))
        elif order.o_type == "PRINT_3D":
            bot.send_message(chat_id,'Все данные введены корректно?' + '\nТип работ: 3D печать' + '\nОписание: ' + str(order.description) + '\nКонтактный номер: ' + str(order.contacts))
        elif order.o_type == 'OTHER':
            bot.send_message(chat_id,'Все данные введены корректно?' + '\nТип работ: Другое' + '\nОписание: ' + str(order.description) + '\nКонтактный номер: ' + str(order.contacts))
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Понятия не имею как Вам удалось попасть в эту часть кода СЕЙЧАС. обратитесь к администратору')

        data_chek_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True, one_time_keyboard= True)
        data_chek_button1 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('yes')
        data_chek_button2 = telebot.types.KeyboardButton('no')
        data_chek_markup.add(data_chek_button1, data_chek_button2)
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'да или нет?', reply_markup= data_chek_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, accept_data)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'oooops')

def accept_data(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    order = order_dict[chat_id]
    if message.text == 'yes':
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заказ отправлен на обработку. С вями свяжуться по указанному номеру!')
        to_db = [order.o_type, order.description, order.contacts, chat_id]
        sqlighter.sql_insert_order(sqlighter.sql_connection(), to_db)
    elif message.text == 'no':
        order.clean_order()

        markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('да', callback_data= 'TO_ORDER')
        btn2 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('нет', callback_data= 'ПОКА НЕ ПРИДУМАЛ ЧТО ТУТ ПИСАТЬ')
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Заполните заявку заново?')
        bot.clear_step_handler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать оператор `return` в функциях, где это возможно.
Также я запускаю ваш код и проблем у меня с ним нет - то вам, возможно, стоит понизить версию Python до 3.7.x-3.8.x.

Также советую переносить логику функции, которая оборачивается декоратором `@bot.callback_query_handler` в другую функцию, используя оператор `return`, например:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ['LASER','PRINT_3D','OTHER'])
def laser(call):
    if call.data == 'LASER':
        return func(call.message)

def func(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Опишите вид работ')
    return bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, your_func)
...
```

Это будет полезно в том случае, если требуется передать локальные переменные в функцию, которая оборачивается декоратором `@bot.callback_query_handler`. Там есть свои нюансы, и если не прибегнуть к этому сейчас - придется немного запариться, чтоб это реализовать в будущем. Можете почитать об этом здесь - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126580/Как-мне-передать-локальную-переменную-в-обработчик-для-inline-клавиатуры-callbac](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126580/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-inline-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-callbac)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, сейчас попробую реализовать ваши советы и напишу результат!

Comment: Не получилось исправить пробему, перешел на либу aiogram. на ней бот заработал, но немного изменилась архитектура, но в любом случае большое спасибо за ответ!